# Vertically center inline-block div inside dynamic height div

Tags: html, css

I've been pulling my hair out trying to make a div center itself vertically.

The div itself contains an svg image, some text below the image, and is floated right and displayed inline-block. To the left of the image, also in the container div, is some text displaying the title. If the text of the title is rendered across >1 lines, the image must float in the middle.

This means that the height is dynamic and i won't know in advance.

I have tried the table solution to this problem, but cannot get it to work due to the div i want to vertically center is already display: inline-block and cannot figure out how to make it work for display: table.

```css
.like-container {
  
}

.like-div {
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 font-size: 10px;
 margin-right: 100px;
}

.title {
 font-size: 40px;
 width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="like-container">
      <div class="like-div">
        <svg xmlns:x="http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/" xmlns:i="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/" xmlns:graph="http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 283.46 283.46" enable-background="new 0 0 283.46 283.46" xml:space="preserve"><metadata><sfw xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/SaveForWeb/1.0/"><slices/><sliceSourceBounds x="12.691" y="27.241" width="269.84" height="254.219" bottomLeftOrigin="true"/></sfw></metadata><path d="M12.691,251.967c0,2.349,1.904,4.252,4.252,4.252h38.293c2.348,0,4.252-1.903,4.252-4.252V131.653  c0-2.348-1.904-4.252-4.252-4.252H16.943c-2.348,0-4.252,1.904-4.252,4.252V251.967z"/><path d="M278.918,147.336c-8.606-14.737,11.983-21.831-5.778-35.607c-22.375-17.355-20.925-14.647-69.32-15.194  c-7.65-0.086-17.099,0.772-14.633-15.114c9.885-63.703-6.41-75.53-17.217-78.504c-22.753-6.26,4.787,19.854-23.702,68.758  c-2.513,4.313-10.086,9.271-15.194,17.567c-10.544,17.125-20.681,44.156-29.436,44.156c-6.252,0-22.42,0-36.091,0v108.504  c20.458-1.617,49.586-3.924,56.862-4.523c11.514-0.949,21.01,6.97,38.104,6.97c15.194,0,24.823,9.421,76.594,1.481  c7.314-1.121,20.896-15.174,18.194-26.576c-2.084-8.804,22.768-15.721,17.405-31.809  C268.403,168.538,290.992,168.011,278.918,147.336z"/></svg>
        <span>Like</span>
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        This is the Title!
      </div>
    </div>
```

I created a plnkr to help show you how it looks: http://plnkr.co/edit/qzqTjQ8W7jl72nRKd6Sj

Sweet jesus help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `flexbox` + `align-items` for centering + `order` for controlling the position, width your existing markup, see the [support details](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), and relevant prefixes.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ehz8wc5/)**

```
.like-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.like-div {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    order: 1;
}
.title {
    font-size: 40px;
    flex: 1;
}
```

If you need to support IE9, you can use this CSS table layout, but you'll need to adjust the markup, place `<div class="title">` before `<div class="like-div">`.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uohL0wj6/)**

```
.like-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.title, .like-div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.title {
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
.like-div {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve vertical centering by using Flexbox. Here is the code

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qbyxkf71/

**HTML**

```
<div class="like-container">
        <div class="title">This is the Title!</div>
    <div class="like-div">
        <svg xmlns:x="http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/" xmlns:i="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/" xmlns:graph="http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 283.46 283.46" enable-background="new 0 0 283.46 283.46" xml:space="preserve">
            <path d="M12.691,251.967c0,2.349,1.904,4.252,4.252,4.252h38.293c2.348,0,4.252-1.903,4.252-4.252V131.653  c0-2.348-1.904-4.252-4.252-4.252H16.943c-2.348,0-4.252,1.904-4.252,4.252V251.967z" />
            <path d="M278.918,147.336c-8.606-14.737,11.983-21.831-5.778-35.607c-22.375-17.355-20.925-14.647-69.32-15.194  c-7.65-0.086-17.099,0.772-14.633-15.114c9.885-63.703-6.41-75.53-17.217-78.504c-22.753-6.26,4.787,19.854-23.702,68.758  c-2.513,4.313-10.086,9.271-15.194,17.567c-10.544,17.125-20.681,44.156-29.436,44.156c-6.252,0-22.42,0-36.091,0v108.504  c20.458-1.617,49.586-3.924,56.862-4.523c11.514-0.949,21.01,6.97,38.104,6.97c15.194,0,24.823,9.421,76.594,1.481  c7.314-1.121,20.896-15.174,18.194-26.576c-2.084-8.804,22.768-15.721,17.405-31.809  C268.403,168.538,290.992,168.011,278.918,147.336z" />
        </svg> <span>Like</span>

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.like-container {
    border:1px solid;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
.like-div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
.title {
    font-size: 40px;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: what is the support like for that solution? what % coverage does it work for?

Answer (score 1):

you may use `direction` and drop `float` : (for old browsers)

```css
.like-container {
  direction: rtl;
}
.like-div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 2em;
  direction: ltr;
}
.title {
  font-size: 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 0.65em);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<div class="like-container">
      <div class="like-div">
        <svg xmlns:x="http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/" xmlns:i="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/" xmlns:graph="http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 283.46 283.46" enable-background="new 0 0 283.46 283.46" xml:space="preserve"><metadata><sfw xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/SaveForWeb/1.0/"><slices/><sliceSourceBounds x="12.691" y="27.241" width="269.84" height="254.219" bottomLeftOrigin="true"/></sfw></metadata><path d="M12.691,251.967c0,2.349,1.904,4.252,4.252,4.252h38.293c2.348,0,4.252-1.903,4.252-4.252V131.653  c0-2.348-1.904-4.252-4.252-4.252H16.943c-2.348,0-4.252,1.904-4.252,4.252V251.967z"/><path d="M278.918,147.336c-8.606-14.737,11.983-21.831-5.778-35.607c-22.375-17.355-20.925-14.647-69.32-15.194  c-7.65-0.086-17.099,0.772-14.633-15.114c9.885-63.703-6.41-75.53-17.217-78.504c-22.753-6.26,4.787,19.854-23.702,68.758  c-2.513,4.313-10.086,9.271-15.194,17.567c-10.544,17.125-20.681,44.156-29.436,44.156c-6.252,0-22.42,0-36.091,0v108.504  c20.458-1.617,49.586-3.924,56.862-4.523c11.514-0.949,21.01,6.97,38.104,6.97c15.194,0,24.823,9.421,76.594,1.481  c7.314-1.121,20.896-15.174,18.194-26.576c-2.084-8.804,22.768-15.721,17.405-31.809  C268.403,168.538,290.992,168.011,278.918,147.336z"/></svg>
        <span>Like</span>
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        This is<br/> the Title!
      </div>
    </div>
```

or use `display:flex;` for young browsers (most efficient IMHO )

```css
.like-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse
}
.like-div {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}
.title {
  font-size: 40px;
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="like-container">
      <div class="like-div">
        <svg xmlns:x="http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/" xmlns:i="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/" xmlns:graph="http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 283.46 283.46" enable-background="new 0 0 283.46 283.46" xml:space="preserve"><metadata><sfw xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/SaveForWeb/1.0/"><slices/><sliceSourceBounds x="12.691" y="27.241" width="269.84" height="254.219" bottomLeftOrigin="true"/></sfw></metadata><path d="M12.691,251.967c0,2.349,1.904,4.252,4.252,4.252h38.293c2.348,0,4.252-1.903,4.252-4.252V131.653  c0-2.348-1.904-4.252-4.252-4.252H16.943c-2.348,0-4.252,1.904-4.252,4.252V251.967z"/><path d="M278.918,147.336c-8.606-14.737,11.983-21.831-5.778-35.607c-22.375-17.355-20.925-14.647-69.32-15.194  c-7.65-0.086-17.099,0.772-14.633-15.114c9.885-63.703-6.41-75.53-17.217-78.504c-22.753-6.26,4.787,19.854-23.702,68.758  c-2.513,4.313-10.086,9.271-15.194,17.567c-10.544,17.125-20.681,44.156-29.436,44.156c-6.252,0-22.42,0-36.091,0v108.504  c20.458-1.617,49.586-3.924,56.862-4.523c11.514-0.949,21.01,6.97,38.104,6.97c15.194,0,24.823,9.421,76.594,1.481  c7.314-1.121,20.896-15.174,18.194-26.576c-2.084-8.804,22.768-15.721,17.405-31.809  C268.403,168.538,290.992,168.011,278.918,147.336z"/></svg>
        <span>Like</span>
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        This is<br/> the Title!
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

this may help you, here is a centered div in the most general form

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>my div here</div>
```

Comment: Won't work when the dimensions aren't fixed, namely when you want to use inline-block for sizing as the question does.